# MenuItem click event won't fire

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have this Menu in my App:

```
<Menu Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="84,66,0,0" Name="menu1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200">
        <MenuItem Header="File" />
        <MenuItem Header="Youtube" Name="myYouTube" Click="MenuItem_Click">
            <MenuItem Header="Login"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Logout"/>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Help" />
    </Menu>
```

And when i click `myYouTube` then `MenuItem_Click` won't fire.

Any idea why i happen?

Comment: Make sure the method "MenuItem_Click" does exist and it doesn't have a typo, etc.

Comment: Does it fire if you put it onto the File menu? Because if you have subitems, it would make sense to not fire it but instead show the menu of subitems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have sub-menu items the event will not be raised se: [`MenuItem.Click Event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem.click.aspx)
But maybe you could use the SubmenuOpened event se: [`MenuItem.SubmenuOpened Event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem.submenuopened.aspx)

I changed it to the events for WPF now.

Comment: I don't Found Popup event in MenuItem

Comment: @MTA, sorry about that I got confused, that was for WinForms. I have changed it to WPF now.

Comment: "The Click event does not occur if the MenuItem has a submenu." Whose idea was this?? :\